# Being "onboarded into the platform" vs "onboarded to the platform"

Tags: word-usage

In this context, a *platform* is an on-line service. The process of registering new users is known as *onboarding*. I do not know if describing such process as *onboarding users **to** the platform* or *onboarding users **into** the platform*.

Comment: Have you ruled out *onto* the platform?

Comment: No, I have not ruled it out. If that's the correct or idiomatic form, I'll take it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In business jargon, *onboarding* is registering, assimilating, training, and setting up a new employee to be able to do their new job.  It therefore adds little or nothing to the concept of simply *registering* a new user to the platform, unless there is also an element of training and mentoring new users as they register.

If it must be used for some reason (perhaps to do with corporate conventions that require this jargon), it seems better to register the users **to** the platform rather than registering them **into** and also **on**(board) it. One preposition seems sufficient rather than two that merely confuse and muddle.